# Will employees paid in Bitcoin, etc be subject to capital gains upon transferring to fiat in the US?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, cryptocurrency

A company is able to pay its employees either partially or at 100% in Bitcoin. The company reports and withholds the appropriate USD equivalent on the employee's tax return.

If the employee holds the bitcoin and its value increases/decreases over a few months/years, will the employee be subject to capital gains/losses on the bitcoin when selling it for a fiat such as USD in the United States?

Comment: What kind of (legitimate) company is paying employees in Bitcoin?

Comment: Presumably companies who do a lot of work with the currencies, such as bitcoin unlimited, Ethereum foundation, coinbase

Comment: The logistics of paying employees in a currency that volatile would be interesting to say the least.